# Redirect Wordpress Media attachment page to root location

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hook

My old website structure used to be `example.com/wp`. I have moved to `example.com`

SO now I am trying to use `wp_redirect` to redirect 301 all my media attachment pages(over 1500 pages) like this:

```
example.com/wp/image1  ====> example.com/image1
```

I am using this hook

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpsites_attachment_redirect' );
function wpsites_attachment_redirect(){
global $post;
if ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent != 0) ) :
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ), 301 );
    exit();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

And the idea is to make `wp_redirect( example.com/>Any attachment link here<, 301 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought and here is the solution:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpsites_attachment_redirect' );
function wpsites_attachment_redirect(){
global $post;
if ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent != 0) ) :

    $actual_link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $actual_link = $actual_link.'/'.$post->post_parent;
    $actual_link = str_replace('/wp/','/',$actual_link);
    wp_redirect( $actual_link, 301 );
    exit();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file image.php

Paste the code into the file and upload it to your themes root directory.

```
<?php wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ), 301 ); exit; ?>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have over 1500 attachments to redirect so that will take me forever. a hook would be nice.

Comment: Mrjack @hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

a alternative file image.php compatible with  media attachment page  without post-parent!
(it's a mix with the two others answers)

```
<?php if ( is_attachment() && isset($post->post_parent) && is_numeric($post->post_parent) && ($post->post_parent != 0) ) :

wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ), 301 ); exit;

endif; ?>

<?php wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('wpurl'), 301 ); exit; ?>
```